# Special Drop-Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, menu

I am trying to achieve a simple drop-down menu with the following HTML structure. This structure is mandatory (I think) as explained in the illustrations below.

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul id="main-menu" class="nav top-nav clearfix">
        <li id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu nav clearfix">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1.1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1.2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1.3/a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="sub-menu-2" class="sub-menu nav clearfix">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2.1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2.2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2.3/a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

To get a better idea of what I am trying to achieve I've made the following illustrations:

1. Simple menu with items arranged with inline blocks. As you can see, the menu scales to 100% of the container and has all the items arranged in center.

[image: This is how the menu looks when the mouse is not hovering any menu item]

2. When hovering over a menu item which has a submenu. In the illustration that's Menu 1 which has Sub Menu 1 and it needs to display it on mouse hover, like a simple `<ul><li><ul></ul></li></ul>` would do. As you can see the submenu has to scale to 100% of the container and has all the items arranged in center.

[image: When hovering over one item with a submenu]

I think the best approach is with javascript (not sure you can do this with only CSS), but I am kind off stuck. The sub menu appears on main menu item hover, but as soon as I hover out into the sub menu in order to navigate, the sub menu disappears. Anyway, this is the javascript:

```
$('nav #main-menu .menu-item a').hover(
    function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        id = id.substr(id.length - 1);
        submenu = $('#sub-menu-' + id);
        submenu.show();
    }, 
    function() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        id = id.substr(id.length - 1);
        submenu = $('#sub-menu-' + id);
        submenu.hide();
    }
);
```

I am pretty sure that there is a better way to do this.

I've also set up a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3z8MR/4/) for better understanding.

Comment: It's because when you hover 'into' the sub-menu, you are really hovering 'out' of the main menu, and the off hover function gets called. Working on a full solution.

Comment: CSS ONLY solution http://jsfiddle.net/5ths8/. It's hacky, but you should be able to figure it out and adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//show sub menu when we hover over an item
$('nav #main-menu > .menu-item')
 .on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.substr(id.length - 1);
    $('#sub-menu-' + id).show();
  });

//hide submenu when the mouse goes away
$('nav').on('mouseleave', function() { $('.sub-menu').hide(); });
```

Modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3z8MR/10/

**Edit**
Add this line to conform to your specs in the comments

```
$('.sub-menu').on('mouseleave', function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Comment: Ah, that was a good point. I've removed my answer, as it is not valid.

Comment: Everything seems ok, except there is a little bug. The submenu should be active (displayed) only when you've got your mouse over his parent (main menu item) or on itself. Your's stays active withing all the area of `nav`. For eg. if I hover over `Menu 10` => `Submenu 1` appears. If i keep my pointer over the `nav` area and don't touch any of the other items from main menu, the sub menu keeps displaying which is not supposed to do so. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It seems to work as intended so far. I will run a few more scenarios than I'll come back with a solution. Anyway thank you very much!